# installing e1071 in R on ubuntu interface

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, svm

I am unable to install e1071 on my ubuntu machine.

I tried using:

```
  sudo apt-get install r-cran-e1071
```

gives an error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In open.connection(con, "r") :
unable to connect to 'cran.r-project.org' on port 80.
2:  E: Unable to locate package r-cran-e1071
```

and

```
 install.packages("e1071", dep = TRUE, type = "source")
```

gives an error message:

```
 package ‘e1071’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

sessionInfo() gives:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN       LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=en_IN       
[4] LC_COLLATE=en_IN     LC_MONETARY=en_IN    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN   
[7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C        
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tcltk_2.15.2 tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? Is there an error message?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra : changed the question, with details as requested

Comment: 2.15.2 is very very old. Update R to 3.something and you should be able to install it via `install.packages`. If you really need an ancient R version you have to download the package code manually from the archive link you can find on any CRAN mirror site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `e1071` depends on package `class`. The package `class` depends on R (≥ 3.0.0). Hence, you should update to a more recent R version.

Comment: I am not sure how to install newest version. I downloaded the copy of R from cran, But it doesnot have a make file. After ./configure i am now stuck.

Comment: On ./configure,I get the error: configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available

Comment: was able to complete the installation by using sudo apt-get build-dep r-base, prior to ./configure

Comment: i have now installed R, but still not able to install e1071 due to proxy issues. Is there any other way to install the library?

Answer (score 1):

Like @SvenHohenstein already said, the package needs a different version of R. What you can do is get an old version of the package from [its archives](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/e1071/), but you'll probably have to install older versions of other packages. In addition, you'll have to build the old version of the package from source as no binary versions are archived. Simply updating to a new R version is much easier...